# regex: replace '@@' with '@' and '@' with some string

Tags: regex, string, scala, replace

**Problem**:
I'm new to regex, I have string 
`"this @ is @@ sample @@@ string @@@@"`
and have target string `"xxx"` 
so process is, 
replace `'@'` to `"xxx"` (target string) 
replace `'@@'` to `'@'` 
so output will look like this, 
`this xxx is @ sample @xxx string @@`

*
**what I tried (scala),**

```
"this @ is @@ sample @@@ string @@@@".replaceAll("@@", "\u0000").replaceAll("@", "xxx").replaceAll("\u0000", "@")
```

But problem is what if source string contains `\u0000`, it will aslo replace with `@`

so, comes to regex Is there possible to select `@` which are not subsequent twice, so in case of `"this @ is @@ sample @@@ string @@@@"` we will replace the target string with only that are not subsequent twice, example 
**"this `@` is @@ sample @@`@` string @@@@"** (matched two result will replace with target string `xxx`) 
and than simply `.replaceAll("@@", "@")`

Comment: try https://regexr.com/ . interactive regex too, experiment and learn

Comment: both solutions work absolutely, Thanks,  WiktorStribiżew and @jwvh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
val text = "this @ is @@ sample @@@ string @@@@"
val regex = "@@?".r
println(regex.replaceAllIn(text, m => if (m.group(0).length == 1) "xxx" else "@"))
```

See a [Scala demo](https://rextester.com/VEQC89553), output:

```
this xxx is @ sample @xxx string @@
```

The `@@?` pattern matches either one or two `@` chars. If the match value is of length 1, the replacement is `xxx`, else, it is `@`.

Answer (score 1):

No regex required. (At least no overt regex usage.)

```
"this @ is @@ sample @@@ string @@@@"
  .split("@@", -1)
  .map(_.replaceAll("@", "xxx"))
  .mkString("@")
//res0: String = this xxx is @ sample @xxx string @@
```